# how to set session & cookie and store it and use it with Alamofire , Swift 3

Tags: swift3, session-cookies, alamofire

please someone give me some kind direction , I am totally new in this. I am making an app which will have **login** option. Once I **login** I want to keep the **session** stored so that I don't have to login again and again, until I logout & destroy the **session** . I am using **Alamofire** & **SwiftyJSON** for this app. Here is my code when **login** **btn** pressed

```
    @IBAction func loginBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let userID = self.userName.text! as String
    let password = self.passwordText.text! as String

    if userID.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
        showMessage(myMessage: "username & password required")
        return
    }

    let postsEndpoint: String = "http://xxx/api/login/"
    let newPost = ["username": userID, "password": password] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.request(postsEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newPost, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                let post = JSON(value)
                print("The User is: " + post.description)

                let username = post["display_name"].string
                if  ( username != nil ) {
                   // to access a field:
                   // print("The title is: " + username!)

                    let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let controllerLogin : UIViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "logInSB")
                    self.present(controllerLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    } else {
                      self.showMessage(myMessage: "wrong username & password")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I know what **session** & **cookies** are ,If some kind person tell me how can I implement it using **Alamofire** & **Swift** it would be life saver for me . I am searching it on the net but could not find any suitable answer. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

solved it by myself . here at my **loginBtnPressed** **function** I set some **keys** like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(post["user_id"].int, forKey: "user_id")
UserDefaults.standard.set(post["user_email"].stringValue, forKey: "user_email")
UserDefaults.standard.set(post["display_name"].stringValue, forKey: "display_name")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and finally in the **AppDelegate** I checked and called it like this below

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let getUserID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_id")

    if getUserID != nil {

        let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controllerLogin : UIViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = controllerLogin
    }

    return true
}
```